# Prove that for all integers $n > 3$, $y_{n+1} = 2 x_n$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $x_n$ be the number of 0/1 strings of length $n$, not including the sequence 010. Let $y_n$ be the number of 0/1 strings of length $n$, not including 0011 or 1100. Prove that for all integers $n > 3$, $y_{n+1} = 2x_n$.

I don't know where to start with this one, especially with the exclusion of certain sequences.

Any help getting me on the right track would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: One place to start with a problem like this, especially when you feel completely at sea, is to explicitly compute the first several cases, partly to see if what you're trying to prove is true, but also to see if any patterns suggest themselves.  Have you done this?

Comment: Yes, after the first three, I saw the pattern in the length of 0/1 strings. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Your accepted answer is not correct as pointed out by Ross Millikan in his comment to that answer.

Comment: @Rachel John Habert is correct. I made a huge mistake there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT:It is difficult to write this formally, so I'm just going to give you a hint:

For $n\geq 4$, you can write $0/1$ strings of length $n$ in $2^n$ ways. To calculate $x_n$, we should calculate how many of those strings include $010$. You can show by induction that this number is number is $2^{n-1}-n$, so $x_n=2^n-(2^{n-1}-n)=2^{n-1}+n$ (alternatively, you can show this formula for $x_n$ by induction. Also, if you write all sequences of length $n$ for $n=3,4,5$ in a matrix, for example, in the lexicographical order, and then mark the sequences containing $010$, you get a nice pattern, which may help you understand where did this number come from:$$\begin{bmatrix}n=3 & n=4
\\000&0000
\\001&0001
\\010(X)&0010(X)
\\011&0011
\\100&0100(X)
\\101&0101(X)
\\110&0110
\\111&0111
\\&1000
\\&1001
\\&1010(X)
\\&1011
\\&1100
\\&1101
\\&1110
\\&1111
\end{bmatrix}$$
for $n=5$ the marks make something like $(X)-(X)(X)-(X)(X)(X)(X)-(X)-(X)(X)-(X)$, and so on).
Assuming the result of the exercise, we should have $y_n=2x_{n-1}=2^{n-1}+2n-2$, which you can also showto be valid by induction (making a similar table may help you again).

Comment: By not including 010, we mean not including 010 as a subsequence.  So $x_4=12$ because we rule out $0010,1010,0100,0101$